# How to use join in finding data in MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb

how to join schema in mongodb?

Example :

a collection

```
{ 
 ObjectId : ObjectId("ABCDE")
 userName : "Jason",
 level : 30,
 money : 200
}
```

b collection

```
{
   Id : ObjectId("AAACC"),
   userId : ObjectId("ABCDE"),
   item : "sword"
}
```

b.aggregate....

i want result is
id : ObjectId("AAACC"), userName : "Jason", item : "sword"

Comment: Is it ok to have items which don't belong to any user?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes, I will handle exceptions according to the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the aggregation pipeline to join two collections and select the required data. I assume here that you have proper identity fields named `_id` instead of `ObjectId` and `Id` as in your sample:

```
db.items.aggregate([
 {   
   $lookup:
   {
      from: "users",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "_id", // ObjectId in your sample
      as: "user"
   }
 },
 { $unwind: "$user" },
 { 
   $project:
   {
      "item": 1,
      "userName": "$user.userName"
      // Id: 1 if you will use your names, because only _id is selected by default
   }
  }
])
```

The first step is [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which joins *items* and *users* collections on `userId` field equals `_id` field in users collection.

Then you should [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) results, because lookup puts all matched users into `user` field as an array of user documents.

And last step - [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) result documents to the desired format.

---

Now sample. If you have following documents in *items* collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18df3e5d85eb27052a599c"),
    "item" : "sword",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c18ded45d85eb27052a5988")
},    
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18df4f5d85eb27052a599e"),
    "item" : "helmet",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c18ded45d85eb27052a5988")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18e2da5d85eb27052a59ee"),
    "item" : "helmet"
}
```

And you have two users:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18ded45d85eb27052a5988"),
    "userName" : "Jason",
    "level" : 30,
    "money" : 200
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18dee35d85eb27052a598a"),
    "userName" : "Bob",
    "level" : 70,
    "money" : 500
}
```

Then the query above will produce

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18df3e5d85eb27052a599c"),
    "item" : "sword",
    "userName" : "Jason"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18df4f5d85eb27052a599e"),
    "item" : "helmet",
    "userName" : "Jason"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18e2da5d85eb27052a59ee"),
    "item" : "helmet"
}
```

NOTE: Usually user names should be unique. Consider to use them as identity for *users* collection. That will also give you desired result in *items* collection without any joins.

Comment: thkank you, it is a very nice answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation operator to join both collections, and then [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) only the field from collection a that you are interested in:

```
db.b.aggregate([
{
  $lookup: {
      from: "a",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "ObjectId",
      as: "user"
  }
},
{
  $unwind: "$user"
},
{
  $project: {
    Id: 1
    userName: "$user.userName",
    item: 1
  }
}
]);
```

I assume `a.ObjectId` should in fact be called `a._id` and `b.Id` should be `b._id`? Either way the same principle applies.

EDIT: had forgotten the [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage. You need this since your lookup will return the new joined field as an array (albeit with one element), so you need this to get rid of the square brackets.